# Is there way to override transitive dependency of log4j 1.2.17 to log4j2 for hadoop-hdfs 3.2.1 jar

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, log4j, hdfs

We are using hadoop-hdfs 3.2.1 jar and it has a transitive dependency on log4j 1.2.17 . In our central NexusIQ scan, it's giving a level 9 issue for log4j dependency. Is there a  way to override log4j to log4j2 or any other solution.
I tried dependency management but there is no jar in log4j2 with artifact id log4j to override the transitive dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to solve the similar issue for hbase-shaded-client jar where I had to exclude log4j 1.2.17 dependency.

For that, I did this.

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
<artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
<version>1.7.25</version>
```

It worked.

[Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842903/cant-use-hbase-shaded-client-jar-because-of-its-internal-dependency-to-log4j-1)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no that's not possible. You don't have a way of overriding a transitive dependency at the Nexus level. You'll have to use a different version of `hadoop-hdfs`, or compile it yourself with a "safe" log4j version.