# Can't use hbase-shaded-client jar because of its internal dependency to log4j-1.2.17(CVE-2019-1757)

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hbase

Is there a way to exclude it.I did give it a try but got ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
I do see that hbase-shaded-client do have slf4j dependency so there might be a way to exclude log4j and use slf4j but I'm not able to.

Comment: Why do you need a shaded client? Also log4j is used as a test dependency, not compilation https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can exclude `log4j`, but you must add back in `log4j-over-slf4j`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>[some version]</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>[some version]</version>
</dependency>
```